# How to decompress a varbinary file in database to a ZIP file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my application, I have to upload a ZIP file and then I have to make it available so that we can download that file again. As I am new to MVC, I have used a varbinary to store the data in the database. 
Here is my view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Createnews", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Createnew</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @*@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Createnews", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {*@
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>File:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        @*<input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Submit" />*@
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        @*}*@
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Complete_ZIP_file, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Complete_ZIP_file, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Complete_ZIP_file, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategoryName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubCategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategoryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @*<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />*@<input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Then I have written the following code in the controller:
     public ActionResult Upload([Bind(Include = "CategoryId,Complete_ZIP_file,CategoryName,SubCategoryId,SubCategoryName")] Createnew createnew)
        {

```
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];

            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));

                createnew.Complete_ZIP_file = fileBytes;
        }}
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Createnews.Add(createnew);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //return View(createnew)
        return View("Create");
    }
```

Now, I the result is getting stored in the appropriate field. Now, I will have to make it available as a download. So, how can I convert this varbinary format to a ZIP file again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need convert to varbinary to zip. you can directly write to response.

```
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        //read varbinary field from db
        byte[] output = GetOutputFromDb();
        return File(output, "application/zip", "fileName.zip");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you levent and ven.
The file name isn't constant. It depends on the file the user wants. Also, GetOutputFromDb... is that a predefined class?

Comment: ok.. 
Complete_ZIP_file property contains onlye file data. you can save file name to db via adding filename property to createnew object when file saving.

Comment: Thanks for that. I do get editing problems though. When I am trying to get that file back from database in the edit view, it is displaying a  "out of memory exception". What should I do now?